# How to make buffers based off of Manhattan Distance rather than Euclidean distance

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, radius, euclidean

I have buffers which need a 1.6 mile radius. However, I want them to be radii for walking distances rather than Euclidean distance to more accurately reflect the data I'm working with. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you define walking distance?

Comment: @Padmanabha I was originally thinking sidewalks, but not everywhere has sidewalks. For my purposes, I'm ok with using non-highways or just regular streets to estimate. Walking distance itself is going to be the Manhattan Distance along these streets.

Comment: Maybe routing is what you need https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/route-tutorial.htm.

Comment: look for "drive time" analysis tools.